# DataFrame columns split (data imported from CSV file)

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe from csv file. One of columns has value as below. The column name is 'location'.

(36.204824, 138.252924)

(35.86166, 104.195397)

(49.81749199999999, 15.472962)

(41.87194, 12.56738)

(37.09024, -95.712891)

I want to split the column into two columns as below:

6.204824 138.252924

35.86166  104.195397

49.81749199999999  15.472962

41.87194  12.56738

37.09024  95.712891

I tried df['lat'], df['long'] = zip(*df.location)

I got below error:

TypeError: zip argument #362 must support iteration

Comment: is this `(36.204824, 138.252924)` string ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Is that because I import data from csv file? It was tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `apply` with `pd.Series`:

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'location':[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]})
print(df)

  location
0   (1, 2)
1   (3, 4)
2   (5, 6)
```

Use `apply` with `pd.series`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2[['lat','long']] = df.location.apply(pd.Series)

print(df2)
```

Output:

```
   lat  long
0    1     2
1    3     4
2    5     6
```